# Automount USB flash drive on CLI (no fstab solutions please!)

Tags: linux, fedora, usb-drive, automounting

I have been looking for how to automount a USB flash/thumb drive on a Linux machine which does not have a GUI. So, it must be CLI-only solution. The most common answer I found was based on editing `fstab` which works for specific UUIDs or `/dev/sd*`. This solution is not good if one is using different USB drives. Or if using two drives at the same time. Or inserting drives after boot. (It escapes me how this obviously substandard solution is everywhere - anyway).

The other solution was based on `udev` but I decided not to try it as soon as I saw that apart from a `udev` rule, it required additional DIY scripts.

BTW, please assume that the USB drive will be different every time and it is possible that more than one USB drives will be attached at the same time. Ideally I would like each USB drive to be mounted under a directory named after its label, e.g. `/var/run/media/MYUSERNAME/MYUSBDRIVE` (this is what I have right now on a GUI-full Linux machine but I am not sure if the solution was because of the window manager, xfce4, or CLI)

What are my options? Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use `automount`? `/etc/auto.misc` has a few entries with which to learn from.

Comment: I believe I tried that but it did not work, dmesg did not tell me anything but I saw the usb there.